# Cannot assign to property: 'lowerBound' is a 'let' constant — becomes let in UIView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a struct:

```
public typealias CoordUnit = Double

public struct StyledAxis: StyledAxisProtocol {
    public var name: String
    public var bounds: ClosedRange<CoordUnit>
    public var distribution: Double?
    ...
}
```

In `SpaceAxisProtocol` bounds are defined as:

```
public protocol SpaceAxisProtocol: Equatable & Hashable {
    var name: String {get set}
    var bounds: ClosedRange<CoordUnit> {get set}
    init(_ name: String, bounds: ClosedRange<CoordUnit>)
}

public protocol StyledAxisProtocol: SpaceAxisProtocol {...}
```

And I try to use `bounds` as a binding in a View:

```
struct StyledAxisView<SA:StyledAxisProtocol>: View {

    @Binding var axis: SA
    
    public var body : some View {
        VStack {
            // Axis name and distribution works
            HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) {
                TextField("", text: $axis.name)
                    .controlSize(.small)
                    .font(.headline)
                
                DistributionView(
                    value: $axis.distribution)
                    .controlSize(.mini)
            }
            // It causes compiler error saying lowerBound and upperBound are 'let' constants But they aren't
            HStack {
                ValueView(value: $axis.bounds.lowerBound)
                ValueView(value: $axis.bounds.upperBound)
            }
            ...
```

When `axis.bounds.lowerbound` and `axis.bounds.upperbound` became `let`? How to edit them in View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange/1782730-lowerbound) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange/1778669-upperbound)! They are really `let` constants:

```
let lowerBound: Bound
let upperBound: Bound
```

`ClosedRange` is immutable. You can't just "change the lower bound of a `ClosedRange`". You have to "create a new `ClosedRange` with a different lower bound".

---

What I suggest you do is:

```
public protocol SpaceAxisProtocol: Equatable & Hashable {
  var name: String {get set}
  var upperBound: CoordUnit {get set}
  var lowerBound: CoordUnit {get set}
  init(_ name: String, bounds: ClosedRange<CoordUnit>)
}
```

If you really like a `ClosedRange` property in your protocol, you can add it in an extension.

```
public extension SpaceAxisProtocol {
    var bound: ClosedRange<CoordUnit> {
        get { lowerBound...upperBound }
        set {
            lowerBound = newValue.lowerBound
            upperBound = newValue.upperBound
        }
    }
}
```

The bindings will look like:

```
HStack {
    ValueView(value: $axis.lowerBound)
    ValueView(value: $axis.upperBound)
}
```

---

Another way to do this is to put the `lowerBound` and `upperBound` in the protocol extension, rather than `bounds`. This way you don't have to change the protocol, or its conformers.

```
public extension SpaceAxisProtocol {
    var upperBound: ClosedRange<CoordUnit> {
        get { bound.upperBound }
        set {
            bound = bound.lowerBound...newValue
        }
    }
    var lowerBound: ClosedRange<CoordUnit> {
        get { bound.lowerBound }
        set {
            bound = newValue...bound.upperBound
        }
    }
}
```